# Getting profile picture of blogposter in Django

Tags: python, django

When I display a blog post in HTML using a for loop

```
{% for post in posts %}
        <div class="blogpost">
        <h3><strong>{{post.title}}</strong></h3>
        <img class="thumbnail" src="{{author.imageURL}}">
        <h7>{{post.date}} - {{post.author}}</h7>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <br>
        
                {{post.context|linebreaks}}<br><br>
                
    </div>
    <br>
        {% endfor %}
```

it works perfectly fine, except the authors profile picture does NOT get displayed. 
I get the posts by getting all posts in my views.py from my models.py. The thing is that the profile picture of the user posting the blog isn't stored in the "post" model in the database. It is stored in the "Customers". Everybody should be able to read and post blogs. The admin (me) can later delete unwanted posts. 
I have tried making a for loop using an array key:value in JavaScript. That is not very secure, because everybody just gets all users and all profilepictures through the whole database. That might not be a good idea. 
This is my models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, null=True)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.image.url
        except:
            url = 'placeholder.png'
        return url

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    context = models.TextField(max_length=250, blank=True,
                                   validators=[MaxLengthValidator(250)])
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    from datetime import date
    date = models.DateField(("Date"), default=date.today)
```

views.py

```
def homepage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated: # Everybody has to be logged in
        posts = Post.objects.all()
        authors = Customer.objects.filter()
        context = {'posts':posts, 'authors':authors}
        return render(request, 'store/homepage.html', context)
```

**That means that I want the user to see the persons profile picture in the corner of the blog post.**

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/files/#using-files-in-models

Comment: That shows something that I have already implemented. The customer has an image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

Comment: Did you read at least first paragraph, about the correct attributes

Comment: Yes, I read it.

Comment: so why don't you then set your {{author.imageURL}} properly after reading it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I think you need to link the author in the Post model to a Customer with a foreignkey:

Then you can acces author fields like

```
{{ post.author.xyz }}
```

Currently your context contains authors as a queryset:

```
authors = Customer.objects.filter()
context = {'posts':posts, 'authors':authors}
```

But in your template you use it as if it were a single Customer:

```
<img class="thumbnail" src="{{author.imageURL}}">
```

And be aware of the typo "author" and "authors"

Comment: It works by using {{post.author.imageURL}} as I have declared a function in my models called imageURL and it gets the URL to the image. Then I used a foreignkey to link them togehter. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you meant by  `{{author.imageURL}}` as author is [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/)( that results in collection of authors).

You probably meant the related author to post which would be `post.author`

Other than that you should pass image URL to template and not ImageField string representation as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/files/#using-files-in-models)

So it should be something in a line of

```
{{ post.author.imageURL.url }}
```